# Добавление только уникальных ссылок в базу

Tags: php, sql

Возник небольшой вопрос про url. Я сделал в базе в таблице поле **url**, при добавлении я пишу, например, в поле адреса nazvanie и получаю такой урл:

```
blog/category/**nazvanie**
```

При следующем добавлении получается, что я снова могу добавить **nazvanie**, и оно будет дублировать предыдущее. Так вот, как сделать, чтобы не было одинаковых? Я думаю делать каждый раз проверку добавляемого имени - есть ли такое уже в базе. Если нет, то добавлять. Может быть, есть еще какие-то варианты?

Comment: @mr-oyvy, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

Механизм `Sluggable` необходим для транслитерации кириллицы в латиницу. В Вашем случае для создания [ЧПУ](http://goo.gl/fQwO50).

[[@msi](/users/2339/msi)](/users/2339/msi) верно заметил, что поле `url` необходимо сделать уникальным, но выброс исключения и последующая обработка, в корне неверное решение. Необходимо дополнительная проверка на уникальность URL-а (дополнительный запрос). В большинство фреймворков встроен механизм создания slug и его проверки, к примеру, [yii2 это делает через поведения](http://goo.gl/wmFbx5)

Answer (score 0):

Можно сделать `blog/category/category_id`, но тогда теряется смысл подобного url'a.

Другого пути нет. При добавлении, изменении названия категории или ее кода (имеюю в виду nazvanie, если у вас оно не совпадает на названием категории) вам нужно проводить проверку на уникальность данного поля.

На самом тебе задача эта отнюдь не титаническая. Сделайте функцию/метод, который будет проверять наличие кода категории в базе. На вход подаете - код/название категории. На выход: true-есть в базе, false-нет в базе.

Comment: В общем, я хочу сделать что-то вроде:

    название_модуля/название_категории/название_материала
    blog/music/tralala

Comment: В таком случае вам нужно создать поля и для категорий, и для материалов. И прозводить проверку на уникальность при их создании, изменении.

Answer (score 0):

Поставьте ограничение UNIQUE на столбец url.

Comment: Тогда при добавлении уже существующего url произойдет ошибка

Comment: значит UNIQUE позволит задать уникальное название, но придется проверку делать, чтобы не вылезла ошибка?

Comment: Ошибку можно игнорировать, а можно обрабатывать.
Вопрос был в том, чтобы не было дубликатов. Их не будет.
Впрочем, есть, конечно, вариант ничего не делать - не добавлять дубликаты. :-)